# Parameterized Test with two Arguments in JUnit 5 jupiter

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, junit5

How can I write a parameterized test with two arguments in JUnit 5 jupiter? The following does not work (compile error):

```java
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(strings = { "a", "b", "foo" })
@ValueSource(ints = { 1, 2, 3 })
public void test(String arg1, int arg2) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Here are two possibilities to achieve these multi argument test method calls.

The first (**testParameters**) uses a **CsvSource** to which you provide a comma separated list (the delimiter is configurable) and the type casting is done automatically to your test method parameters.

The second (**testParametersFromMethod**) uses a method (**provideParameters**) to provide the needed data.

```
@ParameterizedTest
@CsvSource({"a,1", "b,2", "foo,3"})
public void testParameters(String name, int value) {
    System.out.println("csv data " + name + " value " + value);
}

@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("provideParameters")
public void testParametersFromMethod(String name, int value) {
    System.out.println("method data " + name + " value " + value);
}

private static Stream<Arguments> provideParameters() {
    return Stream.of(
            Arguments.of("a", 1),
            Arguments.of("b", 2),
            Arguments.of("foo", 3)
    );
}
```

The output of these test methods are:

```
Running ParameterTest
csv data a value 1
csv data b value 2
csv data foo value 3
method data a value 1
method data b value 2
method data foo value 3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there a way to test the cross product ("a,1","a,2","a,3","b,1","b,2",...) without writing every combination?

Comment: For this the method approach will do the job. In provideParameters you could build up every combination you want.

Comment: @ruediste There is already an issue about that: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1427.

Answer (score 1):

### Best Practices Parameterized Test!!

Consider a simple function to test:

```java
public static boolean isDivisibleBy(int dividend, int divisor){
    return dividend % divisor == 0;
}
```

---

**When generating JUnit5 Parameterized Test case:**

1. Use `@DisplayName` annotation with a message.
2. Use `@ParameterizedTest` with `name` argument.
3. Use `@ParameterizedTest(name = "` with `{0}..{N}` `")` to point to `@CsvSource`'s values.
4. Use `@CsvSource({"key1,value1", "key2,value2", "key3,value3", .. })` without worry of conversion.
   This mechanism is based on implicit converters that can interpret a `String` into another type, such as `int`. This particular example may not seem that impressive, but it works with a lot of very useful common types, such as `File`, `Path`, `BigDecimal`, `Date`, `Time`, `enum` and `URL`.
5. **Don't** use `@Test` along with `@ParameterizedTest`.

Example:

```java
@DisplayName("Divide Test Cases ")
@ParameterizedTest(name = "{0} is multiple of {1}")
@CsvSource({"2,2", "4,2", "7,3"})
void shouldReturnTrueForVariousDivisiblePairs(int givenDividend, int givenDivisor) {
    assertTrue(isDivisibleBy(givenDividend, givenDivisor));
}
```

Pretty Output Log:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using Kotlin language:

```kotlin
class MyTests {
    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("generateArgs")
    fun myTest(myArg: Pair<String, Int>) {
        val (name, age) = myArg // Destructuring; could instead use myArg.first and myArg.second
        println("$name $age")
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun generateArgs() = listOf (
            "A" to 1,
            "B" to 2,
            "C" to 3
        )
    }
}
```